# Get lines until ^$

Tags: python, regex, match

I have this file

```
line 1
line 2
line 3

line 4    
line 5
line 6
```

how I can get from `line 1` to `line 3`?

I tried:

```
print re.match(r'(.*)^$', lines, re.MULTILINE).groups()
```

but I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate little more?

Comment: Is the blank line the delimiter you want to stop on?

Comment: @jgritty yes, the blank line is the stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to use `re.DOTALL` flag in addition to `re.MULTILINE`, in order for `.` to match newline also. `re.MULTILINE` will only make `^` and `$` to match at the ends of each line.

With that flag set, you can use a look-ahead here:

```
re.match(r'(.*?)(?=^$)', lines, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE).groups()
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/UagJuv)

or, you can also do this with only 1 flag set, by look-ahead on `\n{2}`:

```
re.match(r'(.*?)(?=\n{2})', lines, re.DOTALL).groups()
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/Vm3M9b)

Comment: I'd opt for ungreedy here: `.*?`, otherwise it'd match up to the last `\n{2}`

Comment: I think this regex will allow many "blank" lines. I attribute the acceptance to an uninformed poster.

Answer (score 2):

Add the [re.DOTALL](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag to make the dot also match newlines:

```
>>> print re.match(r'(.*)^$', lines, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL).groups()
('\nline 1\nline 2\nline 3\n',)
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a regex for this. It's much cleaner (IMO) to either iterate over the lines and stop on blanks, or else just `split` the whole thing using `'\n\n'` as a delimiter. I prefer this to using a complicated regex because `split` is far more intuitive to read when you're coming back to this code six months later.

```
s = '''line 1
line 2
line 3

line 4
line 5
line 6'''

lines = []
for line in s.split('\n'): # just for line in file if you're reading from a file
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
    else: # Empty line: stop looking
        break

print(lines) # >>> ['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3']

print(s.split('\n\n'))  # >>> ['line 1\nline 2\nline 3', 'line 4\nline 5\nline 6']
```

Comment: I agree with a split type thing. And, if python can use a regex in a split type function, you could use `(?:(?<=\n)\s*\n|$)` to trim up the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Visually, if you want to get lines up until 'blank' lines, this regex should do it.
It requires no modifiers at all.

```
 //  (?:[^\S\n]*(?:\S+[^\S\n]*)+(?:\n|$))+

 (?:
      [^\S\n]* 
      (?: \S+ [^\S\n]* )+
      (?: \n | $ )
 )+
```